# Magento: Block disappear when change language

Tags: magento, block, static-block

I created a custom theme with my Magento Website, in my theme I have a slider and some other blocks but if I click and change language my homepage's blocks disappear and I don't know why, I had a look in the Configuration -> My language store and in the Web tab it's all the same of the "All view store" so I suppose that they take the same options and page, so with all my blocks! 
I don't know where else I have to look, someone can give me some advise? 
Thank you very much!
Cheers!

Comment: Did you check your home page's and block's Store View value? Are they both have "All Store Views" scope?

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, I check my Homepage page and I don't have static block in the CMS -> Static Blocks page, I just built everything through the .phtml files.

Comment: Does logs say anything?

Comment: Thank you again for your help, no, the logs just give me this warning:
2014-11-23T11:56:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:         &lt;/reference&gt;  in /home/imadeiit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2014-11-23T11:56:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:                     ^  in /home/imadeiit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444

Comment: Does your configuration under System > Configuration > General > Design same for all your stores? Did you make any modification on your template's page.xml or local.xml layout files? If so, can you share them for further investigation? It seems like this is a template layout problem.

Comment: I know! I check a lot of times but it's all the same, I didn't understand but this morning I just gived up and started to move all this stuff in static block and put it in the page through Widget... 
Thank thank thank you for your help in any case!